# Преобразование дочернего объекта в родительский Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Есть 2 класса:

```
class MyClass:
    def A(self):
        print(1)

class YourClass(MyClass):
    def A(self):
        print(2)
```

Метод A базового класса выводит на консоль число 1.
Наследник переопределяет данный метод и выводит на консоль 2.
Если в коде создать объект класса YourClass и вызвать у него метод A, то в выводе будет 2:

```
your_class = YourClass()
your_class.A() # 2
```

Задача дана следующая: Реализовать преобразование дочернего объекта в родительский.
После этого преобразования (не изменяя реализации метода A в классе YourClass) при вызове метода A для объекта класса YourClass, выводить в консоль уже должно не 2, а 1.
Т.е. :

```
your_class = YourClass()
your_class.A() # 1
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную задачу, никак не могу прийти к решению.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно так не делают, вместо этого создают новый объект нужного класса на основе существующего. Можно написать метод или функцию, который быдет принимать объект одного типа и на его основе конструировать объект другого типа.

Но если уж прямо очень хочется изменить класс имеющегося объекта, то так:

```
class MyClass:
    def A(self):
        print(1)

class YourClass(MyClass):
    def A(self):
        print(2)


your_class = YourClass()
your_class.A()  # 2

your_class.__class__ = MyClass
your_class.A()  # 1
```

Только сразу предупреждаю, что это очень тёмная магия, чреватая разными спецэффектами и в реальном коде так делать не стоит.

Comment: А вы могли бы пожалуйста описать, что происходит на этой строке? your_class.__class__ = MyClass

Comment: У каждого объекта есть специальный аттрибут `__class__`, в котором хранится указание на тот класс, к которому относится данный объект. Если это значение поменять, то объект будет считать себя уже объектом другого класса. Но данная процедура никак не гарантирует, что состояние объекта будет совместимо с новым классом. Равно как и никак не учитывается какая-то логика, которая могла быть прописана для корректного создания объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить статический метод к классу `MyClass`, который будет преобразовывать `YourClass` в `MyClass`. Правда, в данном примере преобразований по-факту не будет.

```
# @name 66b260a0cf9845989b9d21c897fe9b1a.py

class MyClass:
    def A(self):
        print(1)

    @staticmethod
    def CastFromYourClass(src):
        '''Преобразует YourClass в MyClass.

        Параметр src Экземпляр класса YourClass.

        Возвращает экземпляр класса MyClass.
        '''
        if not isinstance(src, YourClass):
            raise TypeError("Параметр src не YourClass.")
        instance = MyClass()
        # Здесь различные преобразования.
        # Например, instance.data = src.data.lower()
        return instance

class YourClass(MyClass):
    def A(self):
        print(2)

src = YourClass()
instance = MyClass.CastFromYourClass(src) # Преобразуем YourClass в MyClass.
instance.A()
print(type(instance)) # instance - MyClass
```

Можно это же сделать в инициализаторе класса `MyClass`, но придется заморачиваться с перегрузкой параметров инициализатора.

Если хотите также, как и у вас, то вот еще один вариант:

```
class MyClass:
    def A(self):
        print(1)

class YourClass(MyClass):
    def __new__(_cls):
        return object.__new__(MyClass)

    def A(self):
        print(2)

your_class = YourClass()
your_class.A() # 1
```

Вот только экземпляры класса `YourClass` теперь невозможно будет получить адекватным способом, и это даже не преобразование из одного экземпляра в другой.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать monkey patching такого вида, переназначив метод через `__setattr__` внутри объекта, к примеру.

```
class MyClass:
    def A(self):
        print(1)

class YourClass(MyClass):
    def A(self):
        print(2)

your_class = YourClass()
# Вариант 1
your_class.__setattr__('A', MyClass().A) 
your_class.A()  # 1

# Или вариант 2
your_class.A = MyClass().A
your_class.A()  # 1
```